# Find the Saddle Points of $f(x,y) = x^3 +3xy^2-3x^2-3y^2+4$

Tags: partial-derivative, maxima-minima

I started by finding the partial derivatives :

$$ f_x(x,y) = 3x^2+3y^2-6x,$$
$$f_y(x,y) = 6xy -6y$$
but I cant seem to find the critical points from here.

Comment: Solve $f_y=0$ first (it's easiest). There are several solutions. For each of those, insert them in $f_x$ and solve.

Comment: you can use ther second derivative test

Comment: @NgChungTak Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find critical points, we solve:

$$\begin{cases}
3x^2 + 3y^2 - 6x &=& 0 \\
6xy - 6y &=& 0
\end{cases}$$

From the second equation, we obtain $x=1$ or $y=0$.

Putting $x=1$ to the first equation gives $y=\pm1$.

Putting $y=0$ to the first equation gives $x=2$ or $x=0$.

By the [Second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test):

$$H(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}f_{xx}(x,y) &f_{xy}(x,y)\\f_{yx}(x,y) &f_{yy}(x,y)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}6x-6 & 6y\\6y &6x-6\end{pmatrix}$$

Then:

$$D(x,y) = \det(H(x,y)) = (6x-6)^2 - (6y)^2$$

- $D(1,-1) = 0^2 - (-6)^2 = -36$
- $D(1,1) = 0^2 - (6)^2 = -36$
- $D(0,0) = (-6)^2 - (0)^2 = 36$
- $D(2,0) = (6)^2 - (0)^2 = 36$

Thus $(1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ are two saddle points.

[image]

(created using Geogebra)

Comment: I thought that parabolic type is not included as saddle point.  Anyways, thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @NgChungTak What do you mean by parabolic type?

Comment: Intuitively, I thought there's one principal curvature was zero (due to straight line at $x=1$).  I double check that the principal curvatures should be $\pm 6$.  Of course, it should be **hyperbolic instead**.